# What is more efficient in Unity recorded animation or Slerp/Lerp?

Tags: unity, memory-efficiency, efficiency

What is more efficient in Unity recorded animation or Slerp/Lerp? What will be faster?

It is obvious that the animation will take a lot more space.

Comment: [Here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/7994/rotating-objects-script-vs-animation-efficiency.html) it is said that there is almost no difference between both. Is it so?

Comment: Do whatever is easier, then if it profiles as very slow, try the other

Comment: This is almost certainly a premature micro-optimization. Have you profiled and identified a major bottleneck in the way you're animating currently? Typically the reason to go for animations over manual calculations is to get high-fidelity results (eg. capturing subtle gestures in a character, or having a UI element ease and bounce *just so*), while we might turn to calculations when the motion is either trivial (like just spinning) or we're animating procedurally like the characters in Overgrowth. For bottlenecks in animating large numbers of elements, vertex shaders are sometimes an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is almost no difference, but this is often true. Its when you are doing something a large number of times where you start noticing a significant difference. And then, those small optimizations stack up and save you a significant amount of frames. In this case, animations should be more optimized. Wether or not it is best for your game? Depends on what you prefer. If you have frames to spare, but would like to keep your game's size to a minimum, slerp/lerp. Would you like to ensure as many people as possible can play your game? You are probably best off using animations.

Comment: Moving data around can be slower than doing calculations

Comment: True, but in case of animations in Unity i've personally never encountered such a case.

Comment: "Slerp/lerp require runtime interpolation calculations, whilest animations are mostly just reading hard data" this is not true. Animations need to interpolate values between keyframes, and they use the same types of math formulas here too.

Comment: Indeed you are correct... Edited the awnser